# Could not convert the given xpath into WATIR code

Tags: watir

```
//div[text()='#{locator.strip}']/ancestor::table/../../..//a[@class='idit-grid-btn']/i[@class='fa fa-#{var}']
```

I have written the following watir code for the aforementioned xpath but it's not working.

```
element=@browser
          .div(text: locator.strip)
          .preceding_sibling(tag_name: 'table')
          .parent
          .parent
          .parent
          .link(class: 'idit-grid-btn')
          .i(class: "fa fa-#{var}")
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ancestor::table` would be looking for a parent or ancestor element - ie up the HTML DOM. In contrast, `#preceding_sibling` is looking for a sibling element - ie at the same level in the DOM (with the same parent).

You need to use `#parent` instead:

```
element=@browser
          .div(text: locator.strip)
          .parent(tag_name: 'table')
          .parent
          .parent
          .parent
          .link(class: 'idit-grid-btn')
          .i(class: "fa fa-#{var}")
```

Comment: Oopps! How did I miss it? Thanks!